# ¿Cómo registrar la salida de un almacén en la cual salen muchos productos a un destino en una aplicación web de java?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, rest, model-view-controller

estoy realizando una aplicación web en la cual su funcionamiento es registrar salidas de almacén hacia los centros educativos, tengo un problema en el modulo de salidas ya que no encuentro la forma de como hacer para que se registre una salida en la base de datos de MySQL utilizando el controlador y los modelos y a su vez haciendo uso de los servicios REST y su conexión a la interfaz con JavaScript

[image: Esta seria las tablas en la que quiero insertar la información de la salida generada.]

Lo que necesito es que se guarde a información de la salida en la tabla `Salidas` y a su vez en la tabla de `salidas_has_productos` insertar el id de la salida que se genero y el id de todos los productos que se enviaron en la salida y la cantidad de cada uno de estos productos que se enviaron y en la tabla de `productos` únicamente quiero que la cantidad que tenia cada producto que se envió disminuya por la cantidad que se enviaron de cada producto.

este seria mi código del controlador

```
 public int insertSalidas(Salida s)throws Exception
            {
                //Definimos la consulta SQL que invoca al stored procedure:
               String sql= "insert into salidas (fecha,entrega,recibe,Empleado_idEmpleado,centrosTrabajo_idcentrosTrabajo)" +
        "values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
               
                 String sql2="insert into salidas_has_productos (Salidas_idSalidas,Productos_idProductos,cantidadS)" +
        "values(?, ?, ?)";
               
               String sql3="update productos inner join Salidas_has_Productos sp on sp.Productos_idProductos=productos.idProductos" +
        "set cantidad=cantidad-? where idProductos=?";
        
               //Aqui gurdaremos los ID's que se generan:
               int idSalidaGenerado=-1;
               int idSalidas_has_ProductosGenerado=-1;
               int cont = 0;
                List<Producto> productos = null;
                List<Salidas_has_Productos> sp=null;
                        
                ControllerProducto cp=new ControllerProducto();
              //Con este objeto nos vamos a coonectar a la base de datos:
                ConexionMySQL connMySQL=new ConexionMySQL();
                
                //Abrimos la conexion con la base de datos;
                Connection conn=connMySQL.open();
                PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
                PreparedStatement pstmt2=null;
                PreparedStatement pstmt3=null;
                ResultSet rs=null;
                try {
                    
                 
               
                //Con este objeto invocaremos al StoredProcedure:
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                
                //Establecemos los parametros de los datos personales en el orden
                //en que los pide el procedimiento almacenado, comenzando en 1:
                
             
                pstmt.setString(1, s.getFecha());
                pstmt.setString(2, s.getEntrega());
                pstmt.setString(3, s.getRecibe());
                pstmt.setInt(4, s.getCentroDTrabajo().getIdCentrosTrabajo());
                pstmt.setInt(5, s.getEmpleado().getIdEmpleado());
                
               
                       
                //Ejecutamos el Stored Procedures:
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
                
                //le pedimos al preparedStatement l valor de las claves primarias
                //generadas, que en este caso es solo un valor
                rs=pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
                
                 rs.next();
                 s.setIdSalidas(rs.getInt(1));
                    //Cerramos el ResultSet:
                    rs.close();
                
        
                //************ Ejecutamos la Segunda Consulta *********************************************//
               pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                    //Salidas_has_Productos sp = null;
               Producto p=new Producto();
               //roductos.add(p.toString());
              
                    List<Salidas_has_Productos> salidas_has_productos = null;
                    
                    salidas_has_productos=s.getSp();
                    //System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"+productos);
                   // System.out.println("LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL"+salidas_has_productos);
                 productos=cp.getAll("");
                for (int i = 0; i < productos.size(); i++) {
                             
                    pstmt2.setInt(1, s.getIdSalidas());
                    pstmt2.setInt(2,productos.get(i).getIdProducto());
                    pstmt2.setInt(3, s.getSp().get(i).getCantidadS());
                    pstmt2.addBatch();
                }
                pstmt2.executeBatch();
                
                rs=pstmt2.getGeneratedKeys();
                while (rs.next()){
                        s.getSp().get(cont++).setIdSalida_has_Productos(rs.getInt(1));
                    
                    //Cerramos el ResultSet:
                    rs.close();
                }
                    
                   //*********************************** EJECUTAMOS LA 3ER CONSULTA ******************//
                     pstmt3 = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
                    for (int i = 0; i < productos.size(); i++) {
                    pstmt3.setInt(1, productos.get(i).getCantidad());
                    pstmt3.setInt(2, productos.get(i).getIdProducto());
                    
                }
                    
                    pstmt3.executeUpdate();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    
                    throw e;
                }
                    
                 pstmt.close();
                 pstmt2.close();
                 pstmt3.close();
                 conn.close();
                connMySQL.close();
                 rs.close();
        
                //Devolvemos el Id de empleado generado:
                return s.getIdSalidas();
            }
    

Y estos seria el codigo del servicio REST

   

@Path("saveSalida")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response saveSalida(@FormParam("salidas") @DefaultValue("{}") String jsonSalida){
    int a =0;
    System.out.println(jsonSalida);
    String out=null;
    ControllerSalidas cs=new ControllerSalidas();
    Salida salidas=null;
    try {
        
            Gson gson=new Gson();
            salidas = gson.fromJson(jsonSalida, Salida.class);
           
             int r= cs.insertSalidas(salidas);
            
            out = "{\"result\":\"Salida " + r + " generado con éxito\"}";
        
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out="{\"error\":\"Ocurrio un error inesperado.   Intenta nuevamente o llama al administrador de servicios\"}";
        
    }
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(out).build();
}
```

y por ultimo este es el código que tengo en la función de guardar en el JavaScript

```
  function guardarSalida() {
   
 // Creamos un nuevo objeto
    var salida = new Object();
    var sp =new Object();
   // salida.sp =new Object();
    salida.producto=new Object();
    salida.empleado = new Object();
    salida.centroDTrabajo = new Object();
 console.log(productosTotales);
    // Agregamos sus propiedades y sus valores:
    salida.idSalidas = 0;
    salida.producto = productosTotales;
    //salida.producto.idProducto = $('#txtIdProductoS').val();
    salida.empleado.idEmpleado = $('#txtIdEmpleado').val();
    salida.centroDTrabajo.idCentrosTrabajo = $('#txtIdCT').val();
    salida.fecha = $('#datepicker').val();
    salida.entrega=$('#txtNombreE').val();
    salida.recibe=$('#txtRecibe').val();
   

 
    //Revisamos si hay un ID previo
    if($('#txtIdSalida').val().length > 0)
    {
        salida.idSalidas = parseInt($('#txtIdSalida').val());
       
       
    }
   
    $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                async: true,
                url  : "api/salidas/saveSalida",
                data : {salidas : JSON.stringify(salida)}
    })
    .done(function(data){
                //Revisamos si hubo un errror
        if (data.error != null)
        {
            Swal.fire('Error', data.error, 'warning');
        }
        else
        {
            refrescarTablaSalidas(); 
            
            $('#tbl').show();
            salida = data;
            
           // $('#txtIdSalida').val(salida.idSalida);
          // salida.idSalidas = $('#txtIdSalida').val();
           salida=document.getElementById($('#txtIdSalida').val(salida.idSalidas));
            Swal.fire('Movimiento realizado', 'Registro de Salida Guardado Exitosamente.', 'success');
                    limpiarFormulario();
                 //   mostrarDetalleP(salida.idSalida);
        }
            });
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar con mi problema

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a Soes. Es clara tu premisa. Asímismo, vemos que está el insert en Salidas, en salidas_has y el update en producto. ¿Cuál es el problema con ese código?

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentario, asies amigo en el controlador estan esos insert's , el problema es en el insert de "salidas_has_productos", osea la salida si me inserta pero al pasarse a la segunda consulta que es el insert de la tabla de salida_has_productos pues me marca error en el punto de que no esta tomando la cantidad a salir, en esa parte me marca un null pointer Exception

Comment: Entonces te toca ir a [edit] la pregunta y añadir la traza de error completa. ;)